# Get list of physical interfaces in openwrt

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, sh, openwrt

How we can get all physical interfaces in openwrt, I tried with **`ls -l /sys/class/net/`**, But it is not right information.

```
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Mar 21 10:26 eth0 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/eth0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Mar 21 10:26 eth1 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/eth1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Mar 21 10:26 tun0 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/tun0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Mar 22 09:50 wlan0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:01/0000:01:00.0/net/wlan0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Mar 22 09:50 wlan0-1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:01/0000:01:00.0/net/wlan0-1
```

actually eth0 and eth1 are physical and wlan0-1 is logical also.but the result shows differently.

Can anybody suggest a better way?

Comment: Why not `ifconfig`?

Comment: `ifconfig`  will return all the interfaces, but I couldn't see anything that tell the interface is physical or virtual.

Comment: As long as the virtual interfaces are OSI layer 3, then you may be able to compare the MAC addresses returned by `ip link show` to the MAC addresses bound to the Layer 3 interfaces listed by `ip addr show`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python with  the [`scapy` library](https://scapy.net/) to get the interface list.

```
from scapy.all import *
print(get_windows_if_list())
```